# Which is the most recent version of Virtualbox guest additions work with WindowsPE (possibly needing a signed driver?)

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, wds

I'm making a windows (2012) deployment server with a capture boot image.  I'm building a win7 client image to sysprep on virtualbox.  I syspreped it changed the network to boot first and then I get a memory location type of error telling me "a" device couldn't load.  It has to do with a driver because I pxe boot another non-virtual machine just fine.  I tried extracting the drivers from virtualbox guest additions but the latest release drivers get rejected when trying to add them to the capture image.  Does anyone know of a version of the virtualbox guest additions that this worked on? (4.3.6 r91406 doesn't work no matter how many intel 825xx drivers I load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Server 2012, forget virtual box. Use Hyper-V.

Comment: while I agree with you (+1)...I think this is better as a comment and not an answer to the actual question.

Comment: Tried it out with a minimal image and it worked.